# Python-Pandas-Dataframe - Remove only first few numbers from string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract the number before the text begins

```
column1
10units
200 mg
4000units/40mg
40 units
```

The below code worked for all cells except for the cell that had multiple numbers

```
df['newcolumn'] = df['column1'].astype('str').str.extractall('(\d+)').unstack().fillna('').sum(axis=1).astype(int)
```

The output looks like below

```
    newcolumn
    10
    200
    400040
    40
```

Expected output

```
 newcolumn
        10
        200
        4000
        40
```

Comment: Replace `extractall` with just `extract`...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am getting 'No axis named 1 for object type Series' error when I updated with extract

Comment: Just `df['newcolumn'] = df['column1'].astype('str').str.extract('(\d+)')` is good for you.